# Change input value when change select

Tags: javascript

I have select:

```
<select name="Deliveryaddress.Country" id="ctl01_ctl26_ctl00_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_Deliveryaddress.Country" class="form-control">
<option selected="selected" value="Česká republika">Česká republika</option>
<option value="Slovenská republika">Slovenská republika</option>
```

i need insert code phone to input (change select):

```
<input name="deliveryaddress.Phone" type="text" id="deliveryaddress.Phone" class="form-control required">
```

if selected:

```
Česká republika = +420 (I need insert +420 to input deliveryaddress.Phone)

Slovenska Republika = +421 (I need insert +421 to input deliveryaddress.Phone)
```

this not working:

```
$("#Deliveryaddress\\.Country").change(function () {
var rec = $("#deliveryaddress\\.Phone");
switch (+this.value) {
    case 'Česká republika':
        rec.val("+420");
        break;
    case 'Slovenská republika':
        rec.val("+421");
        break;
}
```

}).change();

Answer (score 0):

First. Your `<select>`'s tag id is not `Deliveryaddress.Country`, buy you are trying `ID selector` (further reading - https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Second. You can just write country code inside `<option>`'s `value` attribute, and access it directly from `<select>`'s value, e.g `$('select').val()` will give you current selected `<option>`s `value` (further reading - http://api.jquery.com/val/)

here is the working example of your code

```js
$('select[name="Deliveryaddress\\.Country"]').change(function() {
  $('#deliveryaddress\\.Phone').val(this.value);
})

$('#deliveryaddress\\.Phone').val($('select[name="Deliveryaddress\\.Country"]').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="Deliveryaddress.Country" id="Deliveryaddress.Countryctl01_ctl26_ctl00_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_Deliveryaddress.Country" class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected" value="+420">Česká republika</option>
  <option value="+421">Slovenská republika</option>
</select>



<input name="deliveryaddress.Phone" type="text" id="deliveryaddress.Phone" class="form-control required">
```

Answer (score 0):

this work:

```
 <select name="Deliveryaddress.Country" id="ctl01_ctl26_ctl00_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_Deliveryaddress.Country" class="DeliveryaddressCountry form-control">
```

Česká republika
Slovenská republika

and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $('document').ready(function() {
            $('#deliveryaddress\\.Phone').val('+420')
          })     
          $('.DeliveryaddressCountry').on('change', function () {
              var code = '';
              switch (this.value) {
                  case 'Česká republika':
                      code = "+420";
                      break;

                  case 'Slovenská republika':
                      code = "+421";
                      break;  
              }
              $('#deliveryaddress\\.Phone').val(code);
          });
          </script>
```